# Problem with asp.net mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have the following project structure

http://img13.imageshost.ru/img/2011/07/15/image_4e1fd08fe0c5d.png

**UserController code:**

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View(ValidationResult.OK);
        }
    }
```

**AdminController code:**

```
public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View(ValidationResult.OK);
        }
}
```

**Routes**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );

        }
```

When I try to navigate to http://localhost:2334/admin/login I get **"Server Error in '/admin/login' Application. The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /admin/login/"**

When I try to navigate to http://localhost:2334/user/login I get **"Server Error in '/admin/login' Application."HTTP Error 404 - Not Found. 
**

I can't understand anything :(

Comment: Under which server are you running this? Have you tried recompiling and restarting it?

Comment: Check out your _ViewStart.cshtml in the Views folder.

Comment: `@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Head.cshtml";
}`

Comment: Honestly, i don't know... I would create a default project of the same type and compare the generated files with the ones you have right now. And other information that you can give?

Comment: I have uploaded my project here - http://zalil.ru/31425099

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, probably stupid assumption: Did you define appropriate views for your controllers?
Check this:

```
/Views/Admin/Login.cshtml
/Views/User/Login.cshtml
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to create html pages on each method of controller by right click on action method and add view...

Then from solution explorer app_start -> routeconfig set your default page which gona run.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "YourControllername", // Route name
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Yourcontrollername", action = "methodname", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

Remember you dont need to write controller behind your Home controller in routeconfig for ex just add home if you have homecontroller.

and add view after creating index method that will work for sure.